# Struggling to run my first stored procedure in BigQuery (pivot table inspired by Felipe Hoffa's Easy pivot() in BigQuery post)

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

I have been following along with Felipe Hoffa's blog post "Easy pivot() in BigQuery" (https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710) and I've been able to successfully call his procedure and replicate his example calculations. However, because the data I'm ultimately interested in are hosted in the EU, I can't call his procedure verbatim and have been unsuccessfully trying to create and run a copy of the code into my own personal BigQuery project folder as a result.

As best I can tell, the steps involved are.

1. Copy the code here https://github.com/fhoffa/code_snippets/blob/5163b921398ee29a8010c164a17af05268ac8639/util/pivot.sql
2. Update the project ID and dataset (e.g. swap out every instance of "`fhoffa.x." with my BigQuery info "*blah*.matt.") and create the stored procedure in my own BigQuery account
3. Run the code, adjusting for the new location.

Something like:

```
CALL `*blah*.matt.pivot`(  
    'bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales' # source table
  , 'blah.matt.test2' # destination table
  , ['date'] # row_ids
  , 'store_number' # pivot_col_name
  , 'sale_dollars' # pivot_col_value
  , 5 # max_columns
  , 'SUM' # aggregation
  , '' # optional_limit
  );
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I encounter the following error.

Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `SELECT STRING_AGG(' SUM(IF('||@pivot_col_name||'="'||x.value||'", '||@pivot_col_value||', null)) e_'||blah.matt.normalize_col_name(x.value)) FROM UNNEST(( SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(store_number, @max_columns) FROM` bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales`)) x`, Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "matt" at [*blah*.matt.pivot:5:5]

Can anyone please advise? I'm a novice at Big Query, and can't tell where I've gone off the rails. Apologies if this is a super basic question.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your problem is related to not properly referencing your project.dataset or just simply having typo, etc. - to be on safe side do as below (just copy paste from below)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
`blah.matt.normalize_col_name`(col_name STRING) AS (
  REGEXP_REPLACE(col_name,r'[/+#|]', '_')
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `blah.matt.pivot`(
  table_name STRING
  , destination_table STRING
  , row_ids ARRAY<STRING>
  , pivot_col_name STRING
  , pivot_col_value STRING
  , max_columns INT64
  , aggregation STRING
  , optional_limit STRING
  )
BEGIN
  DECLARE pivotter STRING;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
    "SELECT STRING_AGG(' "||aggregation
    ||"""(IF('||@pivot_col_name||'="'||x.value||'", '||@pivot_col_value||', null)) e_'||`blah.matt.normalize_col_name`(x.value))
   FROM UNNEST((
       SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT("""||pivot_col_name||", @max_columns) FROM `"||table_name||"`)) x"
  ) INTO pivotter
  USING pivot_col_name AS pivot_col_name, pivot_col_value AS pivot_col_value, max_columns AS max_columns;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
   'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `'||destination_table
   ||'` AS SELECT '
   ||(SELECT STRING_AGG(x) FROM UNNEST(row_ids) x)
   ||', '||pivotter
   ||' FROM `'||table_name||'` GROUP BY '
   || (SELECT STRING_AGG(''||(i+1)) FROM UNNEST(row_ids) WITH OFFSET i)||' ORDER BY '
   || (SELECT STRING_AGG(''||(i+1)) FROM UNNEST(row_ids) WITH OFFSET i)
   ||' '||optional_limit
  );
END;
```

So, after above procedures created - below call should now work  as expected

```
CALL `blah.matt.pivot`(  
    'bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales' # source table
  , 'blah.matt.test2' # destination table
  , ['date'] # row_ids
  , 'store_number' # pivot_col_name
  , 'sale_dollars' # pivot_col_value
  , 5 # max_columns
  , 'SUM' # aggregation
  , '' # optional_limit
  );
```

Note: just simply replace **blah** and **matt** with respective proper names of project and dataset

P.S. Obviously you can avoid all this headache and just call Felipe's publicly available proc - `fhoffa.x.pivot`
But I agree, having those locally will allow to adjust those procs to your potentially specific needs and further improve and code - which I see still quite a room here :o)

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail! I copy-pasted your code in, and it worked without a hitch :-) Out of curiosity, you mentioned that you think there's room to improve Felipe's code. Would you mind pointing out what you feel could be improved? And possibly share suggestions for other resources I should check out? 

Regards,

Comment: Accepted! Thank you, again :-)